# Wordpress WPML: I added new language in language switcher but it doesn't show in the switcher

Tags: wpml

So i wanted to add japanese language in the language switcher. I added it in the switcher but it doesn't show in the switcher[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/KFFXt.jpg)

I tried to add new language in [enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/C9Cex.png)it multiple times but it didn't work